# How can I declare Primary Key in Apache AGE

Tags: database, postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

Here, I am creating a `SoftwareEngineer` node. I want to ensure that only one `SoftwareEngineer` can exist against one `SocialSecurityNumber`. **How can I achieve this functionality using Apache AGE?**

```
test=# SELECT * FROM cypher('staff_details', $$
CREATE(e: SoftwareEngineer {
name: 'Muneeb',
SocialSecurityNumber: '12345',
date: pg_catalog.now()
}) RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
```

When I run the above query twice, I got two nodes created that contain exactly same data.

```
test=# Select * from cypher('staff_details', $$ MATCH (v:SoftwareEngineer) RETURN v $$) as (v agtype);
```

Gives:

```
 {"id": 1407374883553281, "label": "SoftwareEngineer", "properties": {"date": "2023-04-01T07:23:10.069163+05:00", "name"
: "Muneeb", "SocialSecurityNumber": "12345"}}::vertex
 {"id": 1407374883553282, "label": "SoftwareEngineer", "properties": {"date": "2023-04-01T07:28:39.245981+05:00", "name"
: "Muneeb", "SocialSecurityNumber": "12345"}}::vertex
(2 rows)
```

Although id attribute is different, but the data is same. I want Apache AGE to restrict creating two nodes with same `SocialSecurityNumber` like `Primary Key` does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on a similar [issue](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/45) on Github. Kindly check it out. From what I have tried and that works for your situation is:

1. Create Function "get_ssn" that will return the property SocialSecurityNumber from the "properties" column

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ssn(properties agtype) 
   RETURNS agtype
   AS
   $BODY$
   select agtype_access_operator($1, '"SocialSecurityNumber"');
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE sql
   IMMUTABLE;
   ```
2. Create a unique index on the property "SocialSecurityNumber"

   `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_ssn_idx ON staff_details."SoftwareEngineer"(get_ssn(properties)) ;`

You might need to first create vertex label (if it is not created already) before running the above CREATE INDEX query as

`SELECT * FROM create_vlabel('staff_details', 'SoftwareEngineer');`

Now when you try to add another node with the same SocialSecurityNumber, you get the error:

`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "person_ssn_idx" DETAIL:  Key (get_ssn(properties))=("12345") already exists.`

Comment: Moreover, I am looking for how to ensure `NOT NULL` constraint in AGE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique SocialSecurityNumber for everyone so that two Softwareengineer nodes have same id(SocialSecurityNumber)

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:SoftwareEngineer) ASSERT n.SocialSecurityNumber IS UNIQUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using MERGE as show below assuming `SocialSecurityNumber` is the *primary key*.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('staff_details', $$
    MERGE (e: SoftwareEngineer {
        SocialSecurityNumber: '12345'
    })
    SET e.name = 'Muneeb', e.date = COALESCE(e.date, timestamp())
    RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);

SELECT * FROM staff_details."SoftwareEngineer";
```

References

- [MERGE documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/merge.html).
- [COALESCE documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/scalar_functions.html#coalesce).

Answer (score 0):

In Apache AGE (A Graph Extension for PostgreSQL), you can achieve the functionality of ensuring that only one SoftwareEngineer node can exist against one SocialSecurityNumber by using constraints and triggers.

**Constraints**: You can create a uniqueness constraint on the SocialSecurityNumber property of the SoftwareEngineer label. This will enforce uniqueness and prevent duplicate nodes with the same SocialSecurityNumber from being created.
Here's an example of how to create a uniqueness constraint using Cypher:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (se:SoftwareEngineer) ASSERT se.SocialSecurityNumber IS UNIQUE;
```

**Triggers**: You can also use triggers to enforce the uniqueness constraint at the database level. A trigger can be created to check if a SoftwareEngineer node with the same SocialSecurityNumber already exists before inserting a new node.
Here's an example of how to create a trigger using Cypher:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_unique_social_security_number
BEFORE INSERT ON SoftwareEngineer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        MATCH (se:SoftwareEngineer {SocialSecurityNumber: NEW.SocialSecurityNumber})
        RETURN se
    )
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'A SoftwareEngineer with the same SocialSecurityNumber already exists.';
    END IF;
END;
```

With these constraints and triggers in place, if you try to insert a SoftwareEngineer node with a duplicate SocialSecurityNumber, it will result in an exception being raised, preventing the creation of the duplicate node.

Note: The examples provided assume that you have already created the SoftwareEngineer label and relevant properties in your graph schema. Adjust the Cypher statements accordingly based on your schema design.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache AGE, you can achieve the uniqueness of the property `SocialSecurityNumber` using **triggers**.
You will need to create the trigger function at first:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_unique_ssn()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM SoftwareEngineer
        WHERE SocialSecurityNumber = NEW.SocialSecurityNumber
    ) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'A SoftwareEngineer with the same SocialSecurityNumber already exists';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, you need to create the trigger and insert the values into it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER enforce_unique_ssn
BEFORE INSERT ON SoftwareEngineer
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_unique_ssn();

INSERT INTO SoftwareEngineer (name, SocialSecurityNumber, date)
VALUES ('Muneeb', '12345', NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('staff_details', $$
    MATCH (existing:SoftwareEngineer { SocialSecurityNumber: '12345' })
    RETURN existing
$$) as (existing agtype);
```

try this query!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_pk(properties agtype)
RETURNS agtype AS
$BODY$
SELECT agtype_access_operator($1, '"SocialSecurityNumber"');
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_pk_idx ON staff_details."SoftwareEngineer" 
(create_pk(properties));
```